# Google Drive SDK : Drive QuickStart App example doesn't work on Android

Tags: google-drive-api

The Drive QuickStart App example doesn't work on Android  (https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-android).

I have a Note 2 running on Android 4.1.2.  I followed all the steps in the tutorial (using eclipse + ADT + google console) and have spent over 30 hours on it.

There is a "ClassNotFoundException" in the following line:
File file = service.files().insert(body, mediaContent).execute();

I found that the exception occurs in Drive.Files.Insert.execute() part.

Has anyone been able to get this camera app to work?  I watched the video tutorial for this app, and even the developer says the app is only "probably going to work"...

Is there a confirmed-working Drive SDK app out on the internet?  All I want to do is to download a simple google spreadsheet from google drive.

Other things that I have tried:
- The DrEdit sample app given by Google is also not syncing properly with google drive.
- I also can't find a working sample app on the Google Document List API website.

I believe that accessing Google Drive from Android should be a simple task that comes with an example...Otherwise, people might as well use DropBox.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

While I was looking how to open a single spreadsheet from Drive, I went thru the same QuickStart app and I was using Eclipse Juno, Windows 7, 64 bit.  I watch both videos, the second being [Integerate with the Android Drive App](https://developers.google.com/drive/integrate-android-ui)

I used the steps from both, especially in my manifest xml.  I had to go the video twice to make sure I had all of the steps. I had to add the user-feature to my manifest.

```
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
```

There were a couple of other things I found.  I was unable to run it on the emulator at all.  Running it on the phone in debug mode didn't initially work either, it could get access to the phone's SD card (obviously).  I copied the APK on to the phone and installed it, make sure your security settings are relaxed.  It worked on my phone (Jellybean Droid Razr) when not tethered via ADB.

Here's most of my manifest. Note you have to replace the 'YOURCLIENTID' with yours from the API Console.  I only used the first set of numbers, nothing after the '-', i.e.  123456789-blah, blah.  Just the 123456789.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.birdsall.tda"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"
     android:exported="true" >

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.apps.drive.APP_ID" android:value="id=YOURCLIENTID" />

    <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.google.android.apps.drive.DRIVE_OPEN" />
    <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.google-apps.drive-sdk.YOURCLIENTID" />
    <data android:mimeType="image/png" />
    <data android:mimeType="image/jpeg" />
    <data android:mimeType="image/jpg" />
    </intent-filter>

    <meta-data
        android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
        android:value=".ActivitySearch" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.birdsall.tda.ActivityMain"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".ActivityTakePhoto" >
    </activity>


    <provider
        android:name="com.birdsall.tda.TDAProvider"
        android:authorities="com.birdsall.tda.contentprovidertda"
        android:exported="true"
        android:readPermission="true"
        android:writePermission="true" />

    <activity
        android:name=".ActivitySearch"
        android:label="Rule Search"
        android:launchMode="singleTop" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

I think I only changed the class name of the activity, otherwise I didn't have to change any of the java code.  Here's my activity:

```
package com.birdsall.tda;


import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

import android.accounts.AccountManager;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.api.client.extensions.android.http.AndroidHttp;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.UserRecoverableAuthIOException;
import com.google.api.client.http.FileContent;
import com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonFactory;
import com.google.api.services.drive.Drive;
import com.google.api.services.drive.DriveScopes;
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.File;

public class ActivityTakePhoto extends Activity {
static final int REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER = 1;
static final int REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION = 2;
static final int CAPTURE_IMAGE = 3;

private static Uri fileUri;
private static Drive service;
private GoogleAccountCredential credential;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(this, DriveScopes.DRIVE);
startActivityForResult(credential.newChooseAccountIntent(), REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
switch (requestCode) {
case REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER:
  if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getExtras() != null) {
    String accountName = data.getStringExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME);
    if (accountName != null) {
      credential.setSelectedAccountName(accountName);
      service = getDriveService(credential);
      startCameraIntent();
    }
  }
  break;
case REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION:
  if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
    saveFileToDrive();
  } else {
    startActivityForResult(credential.newChooseAccountIntent(), REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER);
  }
  break;
case CAPTURE_IMAGE:
  if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
    saveFileToDrive();
  }
}
}

private void startCameraIntent() {
String mediaStorageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
    Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).getPath();
String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.US).format(new Date());
fileUri = Uri.fromFile(new java.io.File(mediaStorageDir + java.io.File.separator + "BCM_IMG_"
    + timeStamp + ".jpg"));

Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAPTURE_IMAGE);
  }

 private void saveFileToDrive() {
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    try {
      // File's binary content
      java.io.File fileContent = new java.io.File(fileUri.getPath());
      FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("image/jpeg", fileContent);

      // File's metadata.
      File body = new File();
      body.setTitle(fileContent.getName());
      body.setMimeType("image/jpeg");

      File file = service.files().insert(body, mediaContent).execute();
      if (file != null) {
        showToast("Photo uploaded: " + file.getTitle());
        startCameraIntent();
      }
    } catch (UserRecoverableAuthIOException e) {
      startActivityForResult(e.getIntent(), REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
 });
 t.start();
 }

 private Drive getDriveService(GoogleAccountCredential credential) {
 return new Drive.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(), new GsonFactory(), credential)
    .build();
}

public void showToast(final String toast) {
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), toast, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
});
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help you much, but yes, I got the QuickStart app working with Eclipse/Kepler.  I had a lot of problems with Eclipse/Juno and also read posts about how Juno and ADT don't mesh quite right.

I am presently using portions of their code to upload a text file from the phone to Drive.  I have a Nexus 4 running 4.2.2.  I note that the minimum API level for the Quickstart app is 4.2 so it's possible that this is where the problem lies. Have you tried it on a 4.2 emulator rather than your Note?

And yes, it is a simple task, but it has to be set up *exactly* right. Drive has its own way of dealing with files (i.e. does not overwrite files with the same name, just creates another one).

Comment: Do they have an example for 4.1.2?  Most S3 and Note 1/2 users are still using 4.1.2

Comment: AFAIK the only example they have is for 4.2. I'm not versed enough in the differences between 4.1 and 4.2 to say.